# Reading data from file into a two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, multiple-columns, fortran90

I'm totally new to fortran and also programming (minor experience). I have a difficulty in writing a code for the following.

I need to store data in a **two-dimension array** using the data from **two input files**
Then I need to **determine the size of the two files** 
Then need to select the variables from both dimensions for a specific value of one variable
and then **calculate the average** 
Finally write the results to a new data file.

Eg:

- There is two radiosonde data files with pressure, height, temperature, dew point values with different data sizes
- Need to get the mean values for height, temperature and dew point, at specific pressures of 1000, 850 and 500 (both files have these records) and  write to a new file.

I have gone through  a couple of books but couldn’t grasp the exact thing I’m looking for. Can anyone of you give me some insight to the coding?  I’m really thankful to you guys.

Comment: How are the input files formatted?

Comment: Here is an example equation about reading in from file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828377/reading-data-from-txt-file-in-fortran

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look something like this:

```
program main
    implicit none

    real::height(100)
    integer::i

    open(unit=16, file='height.dat')

    do i = 1, 100
        read(16, *) height(i)
    enddo

    close(16)

    open(unit=16, file='mean_height.dat')

    write(16, *) sum(height)/100

    close(16)

end program
```

This *assumes* there is a file named `height.dat` with one height value per line, 100 lines total.
It reads the 100 heights in, then writes out the mean height to a file `mean_height.dat`.
You will obviously have to signficantly modify this.
For example, you won't know there are 100 lines in the file, so you will need to use an `allocatable` array for the values you read in:

```
program main
    implicit none

    real,allocatable::height(:)
    integer::i, N

    !Code that figures out how many lines there are
    !...

    allocate(height(N))

    open(unit=16, file='height.dat')

    do i = 1, N
```

This should get you started... Ideally you could start with a simpler input file than what you describe to learn the basics.

Comment: Pressure(hPa)  Height(m)  Temperature(C)  DewPointTemperature(C)
    1006.0          19.0          26.0                20.0
    1000.0          74.0          25.2                18.2
     942.0         592.0          21.2                17.1

Comment: **Thank you @bdforbes,though my  case is slightly different some parts can be used and this will help me with the coding.** 
My input files;           
Pressure(hPa)  Height(m)  Temperature(C)  DewPointTemperature(C)
    1006.0      19.0           26.0                20.0
    1000.0      74.0              25.2                18.2
      ….  ….        ….                 ….
       20.0   26490.0       -46.9               -81.9
And there are two input files like this, same format, different values, different number of lines (records)

Comment: Can you post the files on paste bin?

Comment: input file 1 - (https://copy.com/liwTWfPfGtnI)  & input file 2 - (https://copy.com/Ack0kYUIHemB)

Comment: Once you've figured out how many lines there are (possibly by reading the file through once and then `rewind`ing), you can loop over the following statement: `read(16, *) pressure(i), height(i), temp(i), dewpointtemp(i)`.

Comment: thanks for your comments and suggestions, that helps a lot.   I have worked out the issue with the help from faculty here. He suggest me to use the subroutine.

Comment: `SUBROUTINE Record_No(infile,Number_Of_Records)
INTEGER :: NOR
INTEGER :: Number_Of_Records
CHARACTER(20) :: infile
  
Number_Of_Records = 0
!to Determine total number of records in file 
Open(unit=40, file=infile)
read(40,*) ! to read and skip the headings row of the input file
                                                                          DO
read(40,*,IOSTAT=NOR)                                      Number_Of_Records = Number_Of_Records+1
IF (NOR /=0) EXIT 
END DO
Close (40)
Number_Of_Records= Number_Of_Records-1   ! to remove the empty last raw
END SUBROUTINE Record_No `