# How do I add one space in printing an array in Perl

Tags: perl

I have data which I read and rewrite in perl. My perl printing is as below

```
  my @data = split ' ';         # put read data in an array
  print "@data\n";
  print OUT "@data\n";    # print data into the file
```

The data is written correctly as below

```
AAXX 06064
67403 11480 70602 10195 20183 48521 60054 70322 82530 333 10298 20179 59012 82612 87360=
67413 NIL=
67441 12380 60000 10195 20186 48555 60014 83630 333 10260 29999 59999
83709 86360=
67461 12280 71208 10194 20186 48513 60724 84539 333 10274 20160 59006
84605 87360 91018=
```

The problem is that I have to process this data in Fortran. Fortran usually skips the first column, so reading this data in Fortran leads to loss of the first character.
I would like to be able to add just one leading space on each line. All the posts I have read are talking of removing spaces or adding spaces but not at the beginning.
I hope what am trying to achieve is doable and I would appreciate help.
Also I am wondering why the first data line end correctly (with =) but subsequent lines are wrapping.

Comment: Is wrapping taking place on the screen or in file as well? If on the screen then it might be that data not fit into _terminal width_ and _excess_ printed on next line, if in wrapping happens in the file as well then get sure that whatever you use to verify the file does not have option _wrap_ in state on.

Comment: In your code you use `split ' '` of `$_` variable. But no any further processing taking place. Then why not just use command `print " $_\n"` or `say " $_"` instead?

Comment: @Polar Bear, I don't know if it's their intent, but it does convert whitespace into a single space. For example, it'll convert a tab into a space (`a␉b` into `a␠b`), and multiple spaces into a space (`c␠␠␠d` into `c␠d`)

Comment: @ikegami -- The question is not specific about spaces, but specific that data will be used in **Fortran** program which requires leading space (**Fortran** can not read in case of data. I was a while when I programmed in **Fortran** (university years and other time helped some student with **Fortran** programming) -- I remember that first position in the program was allocated for labels (goto).

Comment: @ikegami -- Just to get some _taste_ of **Fortran** reading some [text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828377/reading-data-from-txt-file-in-fortran).

Comment: @Polar Bear, Re "*The question is not specific about spaces*", I was correcting your incorrect claim that no processing was taking place and that `print " $_\n"` would be equivalent.

Comment: @Polar Bear, Re "*Just to get some taste of Fortran reading some text file*", So what? (And I've written some FORTRAN)

Comment: @ikegami -- OP has written **I would like to be able to add just one leading space on each line.**, my interpretation is that **line** must be _shifted right_  by one leading space.

Comment: @Polar Bear, Yes. So what?

Comment: @ikegami -- Then I suggested print **line** stored in **$_** after single space (no split into array required).

Comment: @Polar Bear, That might be acceptable. Or maybe not. They didn't ask to stop collapsing whitespce into a space. It's good to mention what you mentioned, but it's also good to mention it's not equivalent

Comment: @ikegami -- but also did not mentioned that it **must** be done. My guess was that as the question formulated _poorly_ and OP puzzled with such simple operation he starts _random tries_ to find a solution. OP's profile gives an idea that probably he is a student (Latex + Mathematica + R) and his full name indicates good chance that his origin from Africa. My guess that he recently started to acquire computer footing (I was an employee with University for almost 11 yeas and very familiar with such situation).

Comment: @Polar Bear, Re "*but also did not mentioned that it must be done*", I did not mention that it must not be done. I only said that it would do something different, something you should have mentioned

Comment: @Polar Bear, Look, you asked "why not just use command `print " $_\n"`", and I answered your question.  Stop using the comments for off-topic conversations. Also, stop rudely using bold for emphasis. That's what italics is for

Comment: @ikegami -- sorry, I considered bold to have 'special accent' and not to be rude. I use italic for something important for emphasis but not require special 'accent'. Bold text in capital letters could be taken for _rude scream_ and as I remember never in my life I used it. If you can refer to information policy of usage italic, bold on stackoverflow I would find it useful.

Comment: @Polar Bear, It has nothing to do with SO. Bold is too eye-attracting. It should be used for headers, but not for emphasis. For example, consider that the HTML emphasis element (`<em>foo</em>`)  formats in italics.

Comment: Thanks very much @ toolic and all for your help. A space before the to print, i.e. " @data\n"; does it. I have found that the wrapping is in the original data. The help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is the concatenation (string joining) operator.

```
print " " . join(" ", @data) . "\n";
```

This can also be written as follows:

```
print " @data\n";
```